# Linking CXX executable - /usr/bin/ld: cannot find

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS Experts

I just made a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS.

My old installations was also on ubunru 12.04, and it worked great.

But now when i try to rosmake on of my project, i get the follwing error:

```
  Linking CXX executable ../bin/robot_task_execution
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrw_sandbox
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrw_control
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrw_algorithms
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrw_pathplanners
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrw_pathoptimization
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrw_task
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrw_simulation
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrw_opengl
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrw_lua
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llua51
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrw_proximitystrategies
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lyaobi
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpqp
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrw
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrw_qhull
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Do you have any idear how to fix this?

I installed ROS like this

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full
echo "source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall python-rosdep
```

Best regards
Bjarke

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45651/linking-cxx-executable---/usr/bin/ld:-cannot-find-../) by [Bjarkes](https://answers.ros.org/users/3365/bjarkes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2012-10-11**:
Could you please update your post with the contents of `manifest.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are things I can recommend to check.

1. Make sure your project (and all its dependencies) are located somewhere browsable by ROS, in other words: [Check `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment).
2. Use `rosdep install` : Maybe there are some failed system-wide dependencies.
3. Use `rosmake --pre-clean` : Maybe old compiled objects are making problems

*Updating your question with the contents of `manifest.xml` will be helpful.*

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2012-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1